# Find the values $p$ and $q$ for when the geometric series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

The numbers $p, 10, q$ are the consecutive terms of an arithmetic series. The numbers $p, 6, q$ are from a geometric series. Show that $p^2-20p+36=0$ and hence find the values of $p$ and $q$ for which the geometric series converges.

What I have tried:

$p^2-20p+36 = 0 \implies (p-2)(p-18)=0$

Therefore, $p=2$ or $p=18$.

However, I'm not sure how to approach the part of the question which calculates for q

Comment: Well, one natural starting place might be to declare variables for the unknowns you will need, then rewrite the given information in terms of those variables.

Comment: @Working_dollar You need to show $p^2-20p+36$ before use. You can express $q$ through $p$ from both sequences using $2a_2=a_1+a_3$, $g_2^2=g_1 g_3$ properties for arithmetic sequence $a_i$ and geometric sequence $g_i$. Then you can equalize both expression for $q$ to find equation for $p$. Then you can solve equation (you did it). Then you can put all possible $p$ in any of $q$ expression to get corresponding $q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d$ be the common difference and $r$ be the common ratio of the arithmetic series and geometric series respectively. As $p,10,q$ forms an arithmetic series, we have $p+q=(10-d)+(10+d)=20$. As $p,6,q$ forms an geometric series, we have $pq=(\frac 6 r)(6r)=36$, then by vieta theorem, $p$, $q$ is the solution of the equation $x^2-(p+q)x+pq=0$ which is $x^2-20x+36=0$. This means that $p^2-20p+36=0$ so $p=2$ or $p=18$, the same for $q$. Now the geometric series $p,6,q$ converges when $p\geq6\geq q$, this means that $p=18$ and $q=2$